# Is $\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$ a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups

I appreciate all the help I can get with this task.
$$
G=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
a &b \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix},a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_3, a\neq 0 \right \}
$$

1. Is G a cyclic group?

2. Does a subgroup with 3 elements exists?

All elements in G:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2 \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
2 &0 \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1 \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
2 &2 \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

What do I do now?

EDIT: Thanks for your comments.

3. Is this one subgroup of order 3? $a=1$ generates 3 matrices.
   $$\begin{bmatrix}
   1 &0 \\0 
    &1 
   \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
   1 &1  \\0 
    &1 
   \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
   1 &2 \\0 
    &1 
   \end{bmatrix}$$

From my book

> A group is said to be cyclic if it contains an element x such that every member of G is a power of x.

4. Can $x$ be one of the six elements above?

EDIT: Thanks for all the help! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: You've already got a subgroup of order $3$ staring you in the face. It's not hard to see that no element has order $6$. This takes 2 minutes to check for yourself.

Comment: You could try to figure out the group multiplication law in terms of $a,b$.

Comment: Calculate several powers of these. Also note that $2=-1$ in $\Bbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
c &d \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ac &ad+b \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}
a^n &b(a^n+a^{n-1}+...+1)\\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$

which means $a \neq 1$ if there exists an element such that $\langle x\rangle=G$

$b=0 \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}
a^n &0 \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$ which implies $b \neq 0$ if $\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$ is a generator.

$a=2 \Rightarrow$ $\begin{pmatrix}a^n &b(\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}) \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2^n &b(2^{n+1}-1) \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$

$2^{n+1}=1$ or $2^{n+1}=2 \Rightarrow b(2^{n+1}-1)=0$ or $b(2^{n+1}-1)=b$

if you choose $b=1$ then it will be impossible to find a $n$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}^n$=$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &2 \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Also it will not be possible to find a $n$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}
a &b \\0 
 &1 
\end{pmatrix}^n$=$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1 \\0 
 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$ if $b$ is chosen as $2$

so G is not cyclic

Answer (score 5):

A quicker way to see that $G$ is not cyclic: note that
$$
\pmatrix{2 & 0\\0 & 1} \pmatrix{1 & 1\\0&1} = \pmatrix{2 & 2\\0 & 1}, \\
\pmatrix{1 & 1\\0 & 1} \pmatrix{2 & 0\\0 & 1} = \pmatrix{2 & 1\\0 & 1}.
$$
That is, we have found elements $g,h \in G$ with $hg \neq gh$. Because $G$ is not abelian, it cannot be cyclic.